# Install a downloaded Magento 2 project in Linux Mint

Tags: magento2

I am using Linux Mint. I downloaded a Magento2 project from server and tried to install in Localhost.I changed the URL in `core_config_data` table of Database. I changed database name, database username & password in `.env` file.

I executed below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

I tried with file and folder permission also. In this regard I used `find . -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;` and `find . -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;` command. But I am getting output like below

[image]

Comment: Check your `var/log` folder for log files

Comment: which URL did you entered in `core_config_data` table?

Comment: URL is `http://127.0.0.1/aloquick`. Thanks.

Comment: did you changed database host in `env.php` file?

Comment: Here is the host `'host' => 'localhost',`. Thanks

Comment: server errors (500) are stored in apache / nging error logs. Check your `/var/log/apache2/error_log`  or `/var/log/httpd/error_log`